# How can I retrieve the props which were used to create this actor

Tags: akka, akka-remote-actor

I create this actor:

```
ActorRef eventActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(EventActor.class,1),name);
```

Now, I want to retrieve the props 1, but I can´t. Can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

From within an actor, you can access the `Props` used to create it with `context.props` (Scala) or `getContext().props()` (Java).